# How to share photo on Facebook through my Android App?

Tags: android, facebook, photo

I am trying this, I got success in posting a note but how can I do it for a picture?

```
import net.xeomax.FBRocket.FBRocket;
import net.xeomax.FBRocket.LoginListener;
import net.xeomax.FBRocket.ServerErrorException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Facebook extends Activity implements LoginListener {

    private FBRocket fbRocket;
    int i;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        shareFacebook();
    }

    public void shareFacebook() {
        fbRocket = new FBRocket(this, "PitchFork TRY","c3968bbdd9dc7f44a8e05b7346f46673");
        if (fbRocket.existsSavedFacebook()) {
            fbRocket.loadFacebook();
        } else {
            fbRocket.login(R.layout.main);
        }
    }

    //@Override
    public void onLoginFail() {
        fbRocket.displayToast("Login failed!");
    }
    //@Override
    public void onLoginSuccess(net.xeomax.FBRocket.Facebook facebook) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        fbRocket.displayToast("Login success!");
        Drawable bm = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abook);
        try {
            facebook.setStatus("Hi, Friends this is post by me from my Android App, ");

            fbRocket.displayDialog("Status Posted Successfully!! ");

        } catch (ServerErrorException e) {
            if (e.notLoggedIn()) {
                fbRocket.login(R.layout.main);
            } else {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

from this code I am able to post any text but how can I share photo?

Comment: You can use facebook sdk for android provided by facebook to post images. Is der any specific requirement to use FBRocket.

Comment: how to use facebook sdk for that i don't understand that why i post question here

Comment: download fb sdk https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/   below on this page are the instructions for using and intergrating it with android application. Cheers!

Comment: I download it but there is 3 project and when i am creat through this got error on import file i didn't find jar file where it is ?